# VSCode - show character length of selected text

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to show the character length of your selected text in the status bar?  For example, in PyCharm as well as many other editors, it shows the line and column position. Then when you have some text selected, it shows the char count.

[image: pycharm]

However in VSCode, it just shows the line and column position.

[image: vs code]

But when I select a piece of text, it disappears.

[image: vs code]

Is this a bug in my installation, or is it something I have to enable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be shown by default:

[image]

I notice that your space between "Live Share" and "Spaces: 4" is quite small. Maybe the longer string on a selection does not fit in there. Have you tried expanding the Window or hide some of the status bar elements by right-clicking on it?